# jQuery not change the selected option after load data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why this code:

```
$('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Only work in:

```
load: function (states) {
            $.each(states, function(key, state) {
                var stateText = state.state + ' (' + state.acronym + ')';
                $('#state').append($('<option />').attr('value', state.id).text(stateText));
                $('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected'); // HERE THE CODE WORK
            });
```

and doesn't work in:

```
$(function() {
    loadData(state);
    $('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected'); // HERE THE CODE DOESN'T WORK
});
```

See the complete JS file:

```
var loadData = function(object) {
    $.ajax({
        url: object.url(),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: "false",
        success: function(data) {
            object.load(data);
        }
    });
};

var state = {
    url: function () {
        return 'resources/js/radio/states/states.json';
    },
    load: function (states) {
        $.each(states, function(key, state) {
            var stateText = state.state + ' (' + state.acronym + ')';
            $('#state').append($('<option />').attr('value', state.id).text(stateText));
            $('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected'); // HERE THE CODE WORK
        });
    }
};

$(function() {
    loadData(state);
    $('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected'); // HERE THE CODE DOESN'T WORK
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `$('#state').val(5)`? Here is a **[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vaevkz3s/)**

Comment: And the code $('#state').val(5) get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the async process, to fix this it just removed the double quotes:

```
async: false,
```

In the original code I used quotes in the code:

```
async: "false",
```

Comment: Similar what I suggest the problem was `success` ajax callback was not called when you requires. I don't realise that was for the `async` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation is that: Your `success` callback in the ajax call loads the `<options>` on `<select id="state">` through `state.load(data)` function :

```
    success: function(data) {
        object.load(data);
    }
```

Because `object.load(data);` do the job loading the options: `$('#state').append($('<option />').attr('value', state.id).text(stateText));`. If the ajax call result on error instead of on success this is never called and the options are never load so then when you call `$('#state option[value=5]').attr('selected', 'selected');` after your ajax call the code doesn't work because there is no option to be selected.

Check this out adding `error` callback to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: object.url(),
    type: "GET", 
    dataType: "json",
    async: "false",
    success: function(data) {
        object.load(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
        // console.log or alert... to check if there is an error
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: `jQuery.attr()` returns undefined when the attribute can not be set but not throws any exception, so it's more probaby that what I said in the answers was true. Did you check if the ajax call returns on `error` callback?